# no HDMI audio output device in settings (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, sound, alsa, hdmi

My audio settings window (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) does not show the HDMI audio output, thus I cannot select it.
I only see the regular analogue stereo output, which works fine.

However, I **know** that HDMI output **works**, as I can reproduce audio from the monitor-speaker which I connected via the HDMI, using one of these commands:

```
speaker-test --channels 2 --rate 48000 --device hw:1,3
aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

The HDMI audio device is also **always listed** in the output of these commands:

```
aplay -l
lspci | grep -i audio
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

**None** of the solutions proposed in [this very related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472258/hdmi-is-not-displayed-in-the-sound-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) worked for me.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811497/895786).

I had do add this line

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,3
```

to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, and then restart pulseaudio with

```
pulseaudio -k
```

After that, the HDMI audio device appeared in the list in the audio settings.

I obtained the coordinates 1:3 of `hw:1,3` looking at the output of `aplay -l`

Comment: Had exactly the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 (unbelieavable...), and the same solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

after hours google this problem finally, I found the working solution on [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459541)

step 1 : install alsa tool GUI 
 `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui` 
step 2 : find and open **hdajackretask** tool in ubuntu application list 
step 3 : choose your right codec from combo on top right  ( for me **intel kabylake HDMI** ) 
step 4 : check **show unconnected pins** option 
step 5 : below **pin configuration** part select **Override** option for all of not connected device and switch from **not connected** to **HDMI/DisplayPort** 
step 6 : click on **Apply now** and done. 
ps : if after click on **Apply now** you see **device busy error** click on **install boot override** and reboot you system. 
hope this help you